# How could I demonstrate this convergence of the ratio between 2 rows of a recursive sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

So, let's imagine a sequence $U_n$ defined as : $U_{n+1}=f(U_n)$.

Let's also assume that the limit when n goes to plus infinity converges to a real value Tau. $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(U_n) = \tau$

Well, I've noticed with MANY examples that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(\frac{U_{n+1}-\tau}{U_n-\tau}) = f'(\tau)$

example : $U_{n+1} = \frac{3U_n+2}{2U_n}$

Here the infinite iteration of it converges to $2$, so $\tau = 2$.

With $U_0$ being $1$ :
$\frac{U_{10}-2}{U_9-2} =-0.2499213589$

$f'(U_n) = - \frac{1}{(U_n)^2}$
$f'(\tau) = -1/4= - 0.25$

There's many examples, I'm just giving one here.

The problem is that I'm unable to demonstrate it. How could I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has a meaning if $U_n\ne\tau$ for all $n\ge n_0$, and it holds at least if $f$ is continuously differentiable:

First notice that $f(\tau)=\tau$ (by uniqueness of the limit and continuity of $f$).

Then, by the mean value theorem, $\frac{U_{n+1}-\tau}{U_n-\tau}=\frac{f(U_n)-f(\tau)}{U_n-\tau}=f'(V_n)$ for some $V_n$ between $\tau$ and $U_n$.

Finally, $\lim f'(V_n)=f'(\lim V_n)=f'(\tau).$

A shorter proof uses L'Hopital's rule and requires only the continuity of $f'$ *at* $\tau$.

Note also that in this situation, we necessarily have $|f'(\tau)|\le1.$

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize the equation itself if rewrited that way actually is the lim definition of the derivative of $f$ at $\tau$. So technically that means that what I stated in my late post was correct? That the formula I found is true and mathematically demonstrable (the big part of the demonstration was here). If so, has it already been discovered?

Comment: It is very likely not new.

Comment: ...though anecdotal: it is the "converse" which is useful (if $|f'(\tau)|<1$).

Comment: Yeah, idk if it was discovered, but at least I found it myself, and technically if this formula (in my previous post) is considered as being correct, then we literally can apply it to extend tetration to non integer hight (even complex numbers) to some degree, and we could easily demonstrate all of this mathematically.